# Where can I download the jquery cookie plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I'm trying to implement cookies in my website, I'm using jquery, but I can't find a place to download the plugin itself.

Any ideas?

Comment: The second result on Google: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

Answer (score 33, accepted):

#### Description

You can download it [on Github](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) and use it like this

#### Sample

Setting a cookie

```
$.cookie("example", "foo");
```

Setting with expiry time

```
$.cookie("example", "foo", { expires: 7 });
```

Getting the cookie

```
$.cookie("example")
```

Deleting the cookie

```
$.cookie("example", null);
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment! The link is updated.

Comment: And it also has got some test functions which are very useful.